# {RelativeSource PreviousData} always NULL when used with DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I want to use {RelativeSource PreviousData} with Datagrid. I want to Use that value inside a converter. But with DataGrid it always gives null value. Whereas it works perfectly with ListBox. Do we need anything more to make it work with DataGrid?

Answer (score 0):

The DataGridTemplateColumn does not belong to the visual or logical tree of the DataGrid. This can be solved using a Freezable class according to the solution presented by [Thomas Levesque](https://www.thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/).

```
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }


    public object Data
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Data.  This enables    animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

Declare an instance of this class in the resources of the DataGrid, and bind the Data property to the current DataContext:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <local:BindingProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

The last step is to specify this BindingProxy object as the Source for the binding.